# Groovy: colon mark in closure?

Tags: groovy

I am trying to make my own Dsl and was playing around with different styles of closures in groovy. 
I've stumbled upon follwing snippet:

```
myClosure {
  testProperty: "hello!"
}
```

But can't figure out if this a valid code and how can I access then this `testProperty`. Is it valid? How can I read `"hello!"` value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, lets put aside closures, consider the following code:

```
def f1() {
  testProperty : 5  
}
def f2() {
  testProperty : "Hello"
}
println f1()
println f1().getClass()
println f2()
println f2().getClass()
```

This compiles (therefor the syntax is valid) and prints:

```
5
class java.lang.Integer
Hello
class java.lang.String
```

So what you see here is **just a labeled statement** (groovy supports labels [see here](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_labeled_statements))

And bottom line the code of f1 (just like f2) is:

```
def f1() {
  return 5 // and return is optional, so we don't have to write it
}
```

With closures its just the same from this standpoint:

```
​def method(Closure c) {
  def result = c.call()
  println result
  println result.getClass()
}

method {
   test : "hello"
}
```

This prints

```
hello
class java.lang.String
```

as expected

Comment: Oh thank you so much! couldn't find it in documentation

Answer (score 2):

Usually in DSL you have either this:

```
mySomething {
  a = 42
  b = 84
}
```

which corresponds to property setting

or this:

```
mySomething( a:42, b:84 ){
   somethingElse{}
}
```

which is a method call with Map-literal.

The code you shown is not used as @mark-bramnik explained.